# I'm using Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is my build.gradle (module:app)]

[image: These are my error]

```
Error:In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
Error:In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

What to do?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The consequence of adding begging in for a second time is that you are now on -3 instead of -2, and you have a close vote, when you previously did not have any. If you persist in this behaviour, an automatic question ban will likely be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue like these, I changed like these

```
<declare-styleable name="....">
    <attr name="font" format="integer" />

</declare-styleable>
```

to

```
<declare-styleable name="......">
    <attr name="fontName" format="integer" />

</declare-styleable>
```

in your case rename `android:font` and `android:fontWeight` to custom name